# Images don't display in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I have a WPF app and use Crystal Reports to generate reports.
Everything works great except when it comes to Dynamically displaying images from URL.
The Static Image simply won't change and it drives me nuts.
I have taken all the steps that are described in many online tutorials:

1. insert static picture as placeholder
2. Change graphic location (formula)

My report uses a dataset where one of the fields holds the path to the images on my computer. This field is used as the formula in the graphic location.

The URL's are working when I test them as a hyperlink.

Whatever I try the placeholder image won't change or update. It's like the report can't get access to the folders where the images are stored. I checked the folders accessibility and there are no restrictions, so it should work.

What am I missing here? How can I make it work? Is this a bug in Crystal Report?

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Report Support only FTP for Images, so URL of Image doesn't work. 
You can user RDLC report instead of Crystal Report.

RDLC Reference: [Click Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251715(v=VS.80).aspx)